# python: called function from other file needs modules

Tags: python, function, module, call, nameerror

I am calling a function from `functions.py` into `work.py`, which works fine:

```
 from functions import get_ad_page_urls
```

The `get_ad_page_urls` function makes use of a.o. the `requests` module.

Now, wether or not I import the `requests` module into `work.py`, when I run the called function in `work.py`, it gives an error: `NameError: name 'requests' is not defined`.

I have defined `get_ad_page_urls` in `functions.py` including the module, like so,

```
 def get_ad_page_urls():
     import requests
     <rest of function>
```

or excluding the `module`, like so,

```
 import requests
 def get_ad_page_urls():
     <rest of function>
```

but it doesn't matter, the `NameError` persists.

How should I write the function such that when I call the function in `work.py` everything works fine?

---

**Traceback:**

```
get_ad_page_urls(page_root_url)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-253-ac55b8b1e24c>", line 1, in <module>
get_ad_page_urls(page_root_url)

File "/Users/myname/Documents/RentIndicator/Python Code/idealista_functions.py", line 35, in get_ad_page_urls

NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

---

**functions.py**

```
import requests
import bs4
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_ad_page_urls(page_root_url):
    response = requests.get(page_root_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    container=soup.find("div",{"class":"items-container"})
    return [link.get("href") for link in container.findAll("a", href=re.compile("^(/inmueble/)((?!:).)*$"))]
```

---

**work.py**

```
import requests
import bs4
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from functions import get_ad_page_urls

city='Valencia'
lcity=city.lower()

root_url = 'https://www.idealista.com'
house_href='/alquiler-habitacion/'
page_root_url = root_url +house_href +lcity+ '-' + lcity + '/'

get_ad_page_urls(page_root_url)
```

Comment: Can you post full traceback for that NameError?

Comment: My apologies, but what is "full traceback"?

Comment: @LucSpan The full error

Comment: The only way I can get it to work is when I run the code in `functions.py` and then call the function in `work.py`. I import `requests` in `functions.py`.

Comment: @LucSpan It's like `File "/Users/yelite/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2016.3/scratches/scratch_9.py", line 7, in foo
    return a
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: added full traceback (I think).

Comment: The error is from `idealista_functions.py`. Is that the same file your posted (functions.py)?

Comment: I don't get any errors from requests but i do get one from soup

Comment: I restarted Python, and everything works fine now... :S Also, seems like for every function I add to call, I need to restart Python for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Mine works perfectly fine running on python 3.4.4

**functions.py**

```
import requests

def get_ad_page_urls():
     return requests.get("https://www.google.com")
```

**work.py**

```
from functions import get_ad_page_urls
print(get_ad_page_urls())
# outputs <Response [200]>
```

Make sure they are in the same directory. You might be using two different python versions and one of them doesn't have requests?

Comment: Yes, but your `get_ad_page_urls` does not make use of the `requests` module, which is the issue. Calling the function isn't the issue. Files are in the same directory, and both are written in the same Python version.

Comment: @LucSpan what are you using in the requests module? You should include a copy of each file in the question and the full error

Comment: I've added all files in the question.